# How to Display pdfbooks in iphone except webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Iam getting pdf date from webservice.That webservice pdf link is normally displayed in webview But its performance is not good.So, for this alternative,i want to use like this

```
CFURLRef pdfURL= CFBundle
        //CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("paper.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
        pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
        CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

But for this above coding,pdf file is locally stored named "papaer.pdf". In this place i want to display my webservice pdflink.How to do this.Please guide me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you should accept answers as Perception said.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a very good example for a zooming PDF 
the trick they are using in the above example is rendering the PDF inside a scroll view

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Listings/Classes_TiledPDFView_m.html

assuming you want to load a PDF from a url opposing to a PDF file inside your application 
you can replace with the following line

```
// Open the PDF document
        pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);

        //
```

if you don't want that much of an overkill you can look at Tom Brow's leaves example, its very slick even if not zoomable.

https://github.com/brow/leaves

as a side-note, apple has not posted PDFkit for iPhone and iPad, even if they do have it publicly for osX - I hope they will do so one day.